# SpringBoot @WebMvcTest security issue

Tags: java, spring, rest, mockmvc

I have a spring rest mvc controller which has the url "/public/rest/vehicle/get". In my security configuration, I have defined that any requests for /public/rest should not require authentication.

```
    http.
             csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/home/**", "/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/fonts/**", "/images/**", "/public/rest/**","/login*","/signin/**","/signup/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/property/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and().httpBasic().disable();
```

This configuration works fine when I start my application and submit request using browser or any other mean. 
Now, I have a test class which looks like this,

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(VehicleController.class)
public class VehicleControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private VehicleService vehicleService;


    @Test
    public void getVehicle() throws Exception {
       given(this.vehicleService.get(0)).
               willReturn(new VehicleEquipmentDTO());
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/public/rest/vehicle/get").param("id","0"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());//.andExpect(content().string("Honda Civic"));
    }}
```

Now, when I run this test, it says

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :401
```

When I print the request response, I see it is complaining because of security. **"Error message = Full authentication is required to access this resource"**
Any ideas why it is not working with the security config that I have, and what is the work around to force it to use the correct configurations? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Finally found the reason. Since WebMvcTest is only sliced testing, it would not take the security configurations. The work around is to explicitly import it like,

```
@Import(WebSecurityConfig.class)
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and after searching for a while, I found the following solution.

Because, you have Spring Security enabled in your application, along with other annotations, you can specify the `secure=false` parameter in `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` annotation like this:

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure=false)
public class YourControllerTest {
//All your test methods here
}
```

Explanation:
To disable the Spring Security auto-configuration, we can use the `MockMvc` instance to disable security with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure=false)`

Comment: Thanks. This also works with the handy `@WebMvcTest` annotation which also have a `secure` parameter

Comment: sadly the secure flag is deprecated now

Answer (score 5):

This solved me the same issue

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ClientResourceControllerTest {
```

Comment: This will work but this is different kind of test. "The main difference between SpringBootTest and WebMvcTest annotations is that SpringBootTest annotation will start the full application context. Whereas WebMvcTest annotation will make Spring Framework create application context with a limited number of beans."

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with spring boot 3. Just disabling the filters.

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
```