# MockUser required for endpoint without authentication requirement

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

My `SecurityConfiguration` is configured as follows:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and()
            .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/auth", "/api/auth/**", "/api/oauth2/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .oauth2Login()
            //
}
```

I am testing my custom authentication *POST* endpoints `/api/auth/login` and `/api/auth/register`.  The application runs fine and I am currently writing unit tests for them retro-actively. In my Controller unit test I have the following:

```
@WebMvcTest(AuthenticationController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AuthenticationController.class})
class AuthenticationControllerTest {

@Test
void register() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(post(BASE_PATH + "/register")
        .content(...) // POST body
        .with(csrf()))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

This returns HTTP 401 *(Unauthorized)* instead of the expected HTTP 200.  But if I add `@WithMockUser` (without any parameters) to the test method, then it does return 200.  **Why is a mock user required since I am not requiring authentication on the `/api/auth` endpoint?**  To be sure, I tried setting `/api/auth/**` in the `SecurityConfiguration` but the same issue remains.  I have not implemented anything related to authorization yet, so roles are not an issue.

EDIT: It is worth noting that I tried setting `.anyRequest().permitAll()` as well, essentially saying that none of my endpoints require authentication, but the same problem occurs.

EDIT2: Updated test snippet and I use the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: can you please add your whole test to see how and which parts you bootstrap during the test execution? Please  also add your `pom.xml` or provide more information if you use the Spring Boot Starter for Security or _only_ Spring Security

Comment: @rieckpil I added the information you requested to my question

Answer (score 2):

From this post [SpringBoot @WebMvcTest security issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45116833/springboot-webmvctest-security-issue) I learned that the `SecurityConfiguration` is not imported by default.  So that explains why modifying the configuration has no influence.  If the `SecurityConfiguration` should be loaded I need to add `@Import(SecurityConfiguration.class)` and provide the bean dependencies it seems.

I believe it is better suited for e2e tests, so I am not adding it to my unit test.

An alternative to simply adding `@WithMockUser` to every test method is to add `@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)` to the class. This will disable the security filter.